# Extract the text on the long text

Tags: regex, pyspark, text-extraction

I'm trying the text on the long text .
exemple : the long text is :

- 02.04.2021 09:23:25 CET #PRS~ #PRS~ ( #UID~ ) Tél. #TEL~ #TEL~
  NonConformity 0001 :
  Type of nonconformity : Scratch
- NonConformity 0002 :
  Type of nonconformity : Scratch - cosmetical item
- Il a été constaté des rayures sur L'ENS CASQUETTE réf :
  D54.
- Voir standard doc.
- Nous demandons le renvoi de la pièce pour une remise en
  conformité.

---

---

02.04.2021 09:31:27 CET #PRS~ #PRS~ ( #UID~ ) Tél. #TEL~ #TEL~
Task Completed : 0100 `DEC0`
Decision Taken : REJECT
Justification :

and I would like only with code Psyspark:

- NonConformity 0002 :
  Type of nonconformity : Scratch - cosmetical item
- Il a été constaté des rayures sur L'ENS CASQUETTE réf :
  D5452134500000.
- Voir standard doc.
- Nous demandons le renvoi de la pièce pour une remise en
  conformité.

I try with :
`.withColumn("texte", F.regexp_extract(F.col("description_long_text"), r'([*]\s\D.+(\s*\w*\W*)+)', 0))`

I have a good start, but i would also to extract before --, only

Thank you

Comment: It is not clear. Can you provide sample input and output?

Answer (score 0):

You can match all following lines that do not start with `--` using a negative lookahead `(?!--)`

```
^[*]\s(?!\d|--).+(?:\n(?!--).*)*
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[*]\s` Match `*` and a whitespace character (which could possibly also match a newline)
- `(?!\d|--)` negative lookahead, assert not a digit or `--` directly to the right of the current position
- `.+` Match any character except a newline 1 or more times
- `(?:\n(?!--).*)*` Optionally repeat matching a newline, assert not `--` directly after it and then match any character 0 or more times (change to `.+` for 1 or more times)

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zS2ENk/1).

Or with 2 capture groups:

```
^([*]\s(?!\d|--).+)((?:\n(?!--).*)*)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9KUJLt/1).